# Retain value in HttpModule

Tags: httpmodule

I've written custom httpmodule and it's being called up for every request. I want to store the value on my first request and this value needs to be retrieved for subsequent request. Is this possible in HttpModule?

I know HttpContext.Current.Items preserve the value only for single request and we cannot use Session in our project as per our requirements.

DO we have any other option apart from session\HttpContext.Current.Items for storing values in HttpModule?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a static property.

For example:

```
public class TestModule : IHttpModule
{
    private static string _myVal = null;

    public void Init(HttpApplication httpApplication)
    {
        httpApplication.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(this.OnBeginRequest);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_myVal)) {
            _myval = "whatever";
        }

        //that this is set... you can use it.

    }

    //...
```

}